# Replace callback helper function to pass return value from coroutine into another function

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

```py
import asyncio

async def f():
    await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
    return "return value from f after 2.5 seconds"

def g(x):
    print(x)

async def main():
    ##############################################
    async def callback_helper(original, callback):
        callback(await original())
    asyncio.create_task(callback_helper(f, g))
    ##############################################
    for i in range(1, 5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(i, "seconds in main")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This does exactly what I want:

```
1 seconds in main
2 seconds in main
return value from f after 2.5 seconds
3 seconds in main
4 seconds in main
```

I can only modify the code between the `####################` lines. I cannot change `f`, `g` or the rest of `main`. Is there a more elegant way to do this? It seems weird that I have to define a "callback helper function", first. How can I run a coroutine and pass the return value into another function without blocking? All I want to do is to call `g` with the return value from `f` once it finished. I think there must be something in `asyncio` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative to awaiting the coroutine in a wrapper coroutine is to use `add_done_callback`, which is [available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback) on all futures, and therefore [on tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback) as well:

```
asyncio.create_task(f()).add_done_callback(lambda fut: g(fut.result()))
```

Comment: @rattlesnake Don't worry about the upvote to the answer. I've now upvoted the question - although I don't expect it to be particularly useful for others (the callback-based programming is on its way out, [for good reasons](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/)), there's nothing wrong with it either. And in addition to that - welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @rattlesnake Note that that article is not exactly beginner material - you shouldn't take its criticisms of asyncio to heart. A more relevant article on the subject of callbacks is [this one](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/) by the same author. It's also fairly dense reading, but very interesting, and influential.